# Avoid entering not more than two Decimal Places to column

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I need to restrict entering  more than two decimal places  to the grid column. (DevExpress UI Framework)
Using  following  code, column data is  formatted  as required **after entering** data to grid. But still **can enter** more than two decimal places, need  to allow user to enter not more than two decimal places. Can you please  help with this.

```
GridViewDataColumn discountColumn = gvPricing.Columns["Discount"] as GridViewDataColumn
discountColumn.PropertiesEdit.DisplayFormatString = "#,###.00";
```

Answer (score 1):

**Refer this** - [how to set mask to Grid column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q581035/how-to-set-mask-to-grid-column)

To achieve your goal, assign the `RepositoryItemTextEdit` editor to a column, and set its MaskType property to `Numeric` and the MaskEdit property to "n2". Check the following code:

```
RepositoryItemTextEdit edit = newRepositoryItemTextEdit();
edit.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;
edit.Mask.EditMask = "n2";
gridView1.Columns("Balanse").ColumnEdit = edit;
```

You can also set the editor for a column using the designer. See the below documentation:
[Repositories and Repository Items](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/1009/Controls-and-Libraries/Editors-and-Simple-Controls/Simple-Editors/Editors-Structure/Repositories-and-Repository-Items)
[How to add RepositoryItem to a cell of New Item Row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T161390/how-to-add-repositoryitem-to-a-cell-of-new-item-row)
[How to change Edit mask for each column in a grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T184700/how-to-change-edit-mask-for-each-column-in-a-grid)

> --For ASP.NET GridView

**Refer this -** [ASPxGridView - How to set a numeric mask for a column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T306226/aspxgridview-how-to-set-a-numeric-mask-for-a-column)

Use MaskSettings in aspx for the column

```
<MaskSettings Mask="n2"  ... >
```

Comment: Thank  you very much for  answer .  When  I try  above  method  , I got following  error "'DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridBase.Columns' is inaccessible due to its protection level"   . Can you please  help on this.

Comment: Please remember to add tag asp.net controls.. I have replied answer for the DevExpress winforms grid.. Will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you don't want to allow the user to enter more than one decimal point into the text field on your form?

If so, check out Masked Text Boxes:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2